# I can't find malicious files on server, but the urls work

Tags: security, malware, phishing

Just found a nice way to spend a morning... Google wrote to us saying we have infected files on our website. They sent us the infected urls and it looks like a phishing attack when I visit them. However, when I try to locate these on my server, I can't find them. I looked at the source code of the infected urls and couldn't locate the css files neither on my server. Also, I ran the top level domain through Virustotal.com and the report came out clean. When I copy/paste the infected url in Virustotal, it tells me there's a phishing problem.

So, is there any other way to find the files on the server? Should I contact my host?

There are five files and they look alike except for the hash. After my domain name, here is what the url looks like : /~zczjzzkxzcz/x81/amli.assurance/amli.fr/amli.fr/free/sm/oo/ve/PortailAS/assure_somtc=true/dc0d2f6d7a36af8dfb05869f676736c7/index_2.html

Answer (score 0):

So, after talking to my host, it looks like the problem was from another hosting account that doesn't belong to me, since the username doesn't match (happened since we have a shared hosting plan). So, next time no file is found, contact the host in the first place.